# Haskell Data field as an instance of a typeclass

Tags: haskell, zeromq

I'd like to express a Data type with a field sType to be anything that is an instance of SType (from zeromq-haskell). SType is the zeromq socket type. In the zeromq-haskell source one example is this:

```
data Pair = Pair
instance SType Pair where
    zmqSocketType = const pair
```

Here's what I've got now

```
data SocketOpts = SocketOpts
 { end :: SocketEnd
 , sType :: SType st => st
 }
```

But when I use it like so `socket ctx $ sType so` I get:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
(SType a0) arising from a use of `sType'
```

(socket's signature is `socket :: SType a => Context -> a -> IO (Socket a)`

When I try and create a SocketOpts in ghci I get:

```
let so = SocketOpts (Bind "some") Pull

<interactive>:1:35:
Could not deduce (st ~ Pull)
from the context (SType st)
  bound by a type expected by the context: SType st => st
  at <interactive>:1:10-38
  `st' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: SType st => st
       at <interactive>:1:10
In the second argument of `SocketOpts', namely `Pull'
In the expression: SocketOpts (Bind "some") Pull
In an equation for `so': so = SocketOpts (Bind "some") Pull
```

What I understand from this is that SType is more general that what I've asked for (Pull, which is an instance of SType). How should I express what I want here?

---

**Edit**

This:

```
data SocketOpts st = SocketOpts
     { end :: SocketEnd
     , sType :: st
     }
```

being used in conjunction with:

```
zmqSource :: (ResourceIO m, SType st) => Context -> SocketOpts st -> Source m a
zmqSource ctx so = sourceIO
          mkSocket
          recvSock
          (\x -> undefined)
          where
              recvSock = undefined
              mkSocket = socket ctx $ sType so
```

Seems to be working, but I'll leave the question open in case there's a more elegant way to do this?

---

**Edit 2**

Guys, thanks very much for your answers. Based on your feedback I've now got the following (I won't post it here as it's easier to read on github)

https://github.com/boothead/zeromq-conduit/blob/master/Data/Conduit/ZMQ.hs

I've used a GADT (I think) to try and express the difference between setting up a normal socket and a Sub socket, but there's a wrinkle at the moment: I could use the SockOpts type to set up a sub socket it which case subscribe wouldn't be called and it wouldn't work:

```
SockOpts (Connect "tcp://127.0.0.1:9999") Sub  -- This would be bad
```

Is there anyway to get the type system to disallow this? Something like what I've got in the angle brackets?

```
SockOpts :: (SType st, <not SubsType st>) => SocketEnd -> st -> SocketOpts st
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to express a Data type with a field sType to be anything that is an instance of SType (from zeromq-haskell).

There's some ambiguity in what you mean by "anything" here.

Do you want to simply create `SocketOpts` values with a parametric type, and enforce the requirement for a `SType` instance when the `SocketOpts` value is used? Then a normal parameterized type is fine, as in your edit.

Do you want to ensure that any `SocketOpts` value will have an instance for the specified type, enforcing the constraint when the value is created rather than used? Then a GADT definition will work:

```
data SocketOpts st where
    SocketOpts :: (SType st) => SocketEnd -> st -> SocketOpts st
```

Do you want to use any instance to *create* a `SocketOpts` value, without parameterizing it by the specific type? That's an existential type will work:

```
data SocketOpts where
    SocketOpts :: (SType st) => SocketEnd -> st -> SocketOpts
```

...but be warned that existentials can be awkward, and that all you can do with something like this is pattern match on `SocketOpts` and then use the methods defined for `SType`. Knowledge of the specific type is lost.

Or, finally, do you want to select any instance when *using* a `SocketOpts` value, giving up the ability to create one with a specific type? That's a universally quantified type:

```
data SocketOpts where
    SocketOpts :: SocketEnd -> (forall st. SType st => st) -> SocketOpts
```

...which I believe is what your original version was. In this case, you can't use a monomorphic value to create a `SocketOpts` value, only a polymorphic value--think of the difference between the `Int` value 11 and the numeric literal `11 :: Num a => a`. Be warned that in this case, GHC still needs to know which instance to select, so when using the contents of a `SocketOpts` you'll need a specific type before using any `SType` methods.

The errors you saw both came from the above warnings about universally quantified types: The "ambiguous type" because you applied something that needed to pick an `SType` instance without giving GHC enough information to do so, and the "could not deduce" error because you tried to construct a `SocketOpts` with a monomorphic value.

I suspect that the existential version is what you were trying for. However, unless you have a compelling reason to mix different instances of `SType`, the parametric GADT is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tr GADTs?

```
data SocketOpts where
    SocketOpts :: SType st => SocketEnd -> st -> SocketOpts
```

You can also try GADTs with existentials:

```
data SocketOpts where
    SocketOpts :: SocketEnd -> (forall st . SType st => st) -> SocketOpts
```